# Ultra low power adders and multiplier

Tags: vhdl, low-power, adder, multiplier

I am working on a low frequency 30 khz module that needs to have an ultra low power consumption. The problem is the research focuses on improving the performance of the adders and multiplier and doesn't focus on the power consumption.

Could some one tell me what are the best architectures for multipliers and adders to have the lowest power consumption in nW?

Let me put my question in an other form: What is the adder and multiplier architecture that achieves the lowest power consumption so I can build them using vhdl, knowing that the delay is not an important issue.

Comment: You need to provide some numbers here. We can't know what "ultra low power" means to you. Also, you mention "30 KHz", but how many computations do you actually need to do (per second or whatever)? And what kind of word widths are you working with? Why isn't a low-power microprocessor suitable for this application?

Comment: you are right i should be more specific . i mean by ultra low power (under 100nw)for a clock 30khz the duration of computation is around 5seconds and the word width between 9 and 14.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try looking into bit serial logic. It's slow, but small and thus the instant power use would be low.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the clock rate, you are asking for a few tens of nanoamperes of leakage current. This will be difficult to achieve in practice. I would think you would want to use CMOS with high thresholds to avoid subthreshold leakage, but I'm not sure you can even get the input leakage current down to the nanoampere range. As far as VHDL is concerned, you should try to minimize the number of transistors and the switching activity in the circuit.

Comment: well the stander adders from libraries achieve 100nm for the giving clock rate but i want to get the power consumption as low as possible this is why i want to build my own adders and multipliers  . i tried the RCA adder and it gives similar results to the ones given in the libraries this is why am asking for ultra low power architectures .
concerning the leakage power am in the point where the leakage power is bigger then the dynamic power but using high threshold transistor will cause higher power consumption since the supply voltage must be higher so intend too add 2high threshold nmos

Comment: between the system an the supply and ground